# Net https requests gives me what appears to be hex

Tags: ruby, ssl, https, proxy

In ruby, I'm doing an HTTP GET request to a website that uses SSL, and for some reason it *only* gives me the data I need when proxying it through an HTTP proxy (burp suite).

For example:

```
    if uri.port == 443
        response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, "172.16.38.182", "8080", :use_ssl => true, :verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE) {|http|
            http.request(request)
        }
    else
        response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) {|http|
            http.request(request)
        }
    end
```

by proxying this through BurpSuite, I can see the data that I need. But if I try this below:

```
    if uri.port == 443
        response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, :use_ssl => true, :verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE) {|http|
            http.request(request)
        }
    else
        response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) {|http|
            http.request(request)
        }
    end
```

then I get hex characters that looks like this:

[image]

Any idea why this would be the case? Is it because of the specific SSL/TLS version used or something and the web application proxy knows how to interact with it but net/https doesn't? can't figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the reason this looks the way it does is because it's returned with `gzip` encoding.

I was able to successfully decode it by using the following:

```
    if response['content-encoding'] == 'gzip'
        gz = Zlib::GzipReader.new(StringIO.new(response.body.to_s))
        uncompressed_string = gz.read
    end
```